# Passing in a function, into a function, to be executed later WITH parameters? Possible as a single parameter?

Tags: javascript, function

The following seams to work, at least when tested via console, please let me know if its not the correct way of doing things:

```
function test1(x){
    x();
}

function test2(){
    console.log('test2 fired');
}

test1(test2);
```

Will result in console outputting:

```
test2 fired
```

So assuming the above is correct, how do i pass in a function name WITH parameters? Do they need to be passed in individually? Like this:

```
function test1(x,p,r){
    x(p,r);
}

function test2(p,r){
    console.log('test2 fired - p: '+p+' | r: '+r);
}
```

While the above should work, is there to pass in the parameters as part of 'x' rather then as individual params?

To give a bit of insight, what we are trying to do is basically if a condition is met inside "test1", execute a function, that takes parameters. To simplify further, imagine test1 creates a DOM object, and we want to attach a onerror property to this DOM object. If this DOM objects fires onerror, invoke our ajax function, which takes parameters (url, querystring, method, etc). **We are hoping on being able to do this without any intermediate functions.**

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this doesn't meet you condition on no intermediate functions, but the simple way of accomplishing this is passing an anonymous function:

```
function test1(x){
    x();
}

function test2(p,r){
    console.log('test2 fired - p: '+p+' | r: '+r);
}

test1(function() { test2('someP', 'someR'); });
```